# python find string after linebreak

Tags: python, regex, search

I have 2 strings that contains the following:

```
name = 'Kalvo'
info = 'PC1:\nKalvo (Read)(Write)\nKL27 (Read)(Write)'
```

Now what I want achieve here is to search the info for the word found in name and print out everything after name.

Lets say I'm searching the string info for string name and it should the print out:

```
Kalvo (Read)(Write)
```

I tried using `re.search` and `re.findall` but I can't get them to work. 
Help is much appreciated.

Br,
Toby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to insert the name in the Regex pattern.  Then, using `.*`, you can get any characters after it.  See a demonstration below:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> name = 'Kalvo'
>>> info = 'PC1:\nKalvo (Read)(Write)\nKL27 (Read)(Write)'
>>> findall("{}.*".format(name), info)[0]
'Kalvo (Read)(Write)'
>>>
```